# How are people managing encrypted config files?

Tags: .net, file, encryption, configuration

We have a large series of SVN servers that hold applications for several teams.  We have received a mandate that the config file must not have database connection strings in plain-text stored in the SVN repository.  That is, only the team members should be able to see the connection strings in plain text.  Since we are using .net encrypting the config sections is not too big of deal.  But most methods I have read about require use either a machine specific or user specific key.  Since the machines and users will vary this does not seem like it would work.  How are others managing encryption keys with teams of users/developers?  We do have our own RSA key servers.  Is that the way to go?

Thanks,

jerry

Comment: Hmm, more of a system design issue, but we'll allow it :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, basically you should not store the configuration together with the source.

The configuration is encrypted with a public key, the private key is in a resource or configured separately. It is also signed by a private "code/configuration signing" key, again the public key required for verification is stored or configured separately. Sometimes additional verification and obfuscation techniques are deployed as well. The decryption and signing keys should be for a specific project, or you might swap config files (or run into horrible exceptions when they are swapped out).

Storing plain keys in code is called obfuscation, anybody with access to the source code or binary code is able to find them. Keys preferably should not be in stored in code.

Of course, if you use public/private keys you need to have a PKI infrastucture and the necessary key management. I won't (and cannot/may not) go into that, but I guess the RSA key servers could provide you with the right environment.